# How to config default return type Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, content-negotiation

is there any way to make default content type?

i use this

```
@Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
```

and it works good for methods without produces= ....

this method do not work with this config

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test/{testId}",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<Resource> getTestAttachment @PathVariable Integer testId);
```

when i call this method i got 406 Http error

Answer (score 0):

finally found this way

```
 @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(MediaType.ALL);
    }
```